# ReactJS game - toggling between components -- unable to execute it

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a JSON data and I have 2 components GameIntroduction.js and GameLevel.js.

Structure of JSON file looks like this::

```
export const gameData = [
    {
        "data": [
            {
            "id": 0,
            "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1492725764893-90b379c2b6e7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
            "word": "Mom"
            },
            {
            "id": 1,
            "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1482235225574-c37692835cf3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
            "word": "Dad"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "data": [
            {
            "id": 2,
            "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551445523-324a0fdab051?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
            "word": "Apple"
            },
            {
            "id": 3,
            "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553279768-865429fa0078?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
            "word": "Mango"
            },
            {
            "id": 4,
            "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502741338009-cac2772e18bc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
            "word": "Blueberry"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "data": [
            {
            "id": 5,
            "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1459411621453-7b03977f4bfc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
            "word": "broccoli"
            },
            {
            "id": 6,
            "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531170887152-6b21ba4ce8ae?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
            "word": "cucumber"
            },
            {
            "id": 7,
            "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564874997803-e4d589d5fd41?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
            "word": "tomato"
            },
            {
            "id": 8,
            "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506807803488-8eafc15316c7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
            "word": "beetroot"
            }
        ]
    },
    {

        "data": [
            {
            "id": 9,
            "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518674660708-0e2c0473e68e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
            "word": "Pen"
            },
            {
            "id": 10,
            "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516962215378-7fa2e137ae93?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
            "word": "Pencil"
            },
            {
            "id": 11,
            "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541963463532-d68292c34b19?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
            "word": "Book"
            },
            {
            "id": 12,
            "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1527239441953-caffd968d952?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
            "word": "Papers"
            },
            {
            "id": 13,
            "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551818014-7c8ace9c1b5c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
            "word": "Pendrive"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Now I need to display each object of JSON first in GameIntroduction.js for 30 seconds and then display the same object to GameLevel.js for users to play some game. After some task is completed in GameLevel.js by user then again it moves automatically to GameIntroduction.js for 30 seconds and then to GameLevel.js.
This cycle continues till all the element in JSON is looped. Only one object of JSOn is passed at a time to above 2 components that too in sequence.

I am lost how to do it in Reactjs. Looking for some solid suggestions.

Game image is attached here.
[image: Game_image]

Comment: Can you share some of your code with which you're trying.

Answer (score 1):

```
    import { gameData } from 'gamedatafile';

    const InitialGame = () => {
      return <GameLevel gameData={gameData} /> 
    }
```

```
   const GameLevel = ({gameData}) => {
       const [currentGame, setCurrentGame] = useState(0);
       React.useEffect(() => {
          setInterval(() => { setCurrentGame(currentGame+1) }, 30);
       }, [currentGame, setCurrentGame]);

       return (
            <div>{gameData[currentGame]}</div>
       );
   }
```

The above way can be your starting point.

Comment: Thanks @Y M . I will go through it and try to take off from here.

Comment: Cool. Accept it if it makes sense and edit the answer too so that you can help others :)